How to implement implicit casting and operators for std::variant wrapper class?
I'm trying to implement std::variant wrapper that would behave similarly to std::variant when it comes to assignment and creation but also allow implicit cast to all alternatives held by the variant.
This implementation gives me errors and is trying to use operator () to make Variant out of Variant.
class Settings
{
public:

    class Variant
    {
    public:
        using variant_t = std::variant<std::monostate, int, float, bool, std::string>;

        Variant() = default;

        template <typename T>
        Variant(T&& v) : value(v) {}

        template <typename T>
        operator T() const
        {
            if (std::holds_alternative<T>(value)) {
                return std::get<T>(value);
            }
            return T();
        }

        template <typename T>
        constexpr T get() const
        {
            return static_cast<T>(this);
        }

        bool        GetBool() const { return get<bool>(); };
        float       GetFloat() const { return get<float>(); };
        int         GetInt() const { return get<int>(); };
        std::string GetString() const { return get<std::string>(); };

    private:
        variant_t value;
    };

    Variant GetValue(std::string_view key) const
    {
        std::shared_lock lock(mtx);
        auto iter = data.find(key);
        return iter == data.end() ? Variant() : iter->second;
    };

    void SetValue(std::string_view key, Variant value)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
        data.insert_or_assign(key, value);
    };

private:
    using SettingsMap = std::unordered_map<std::string_view, Variant>;

    Settings();
    ~Settings() {};

    mutable std::shared_mutex mtx;
    SettingsMap data;
};

What needs to be changed to allow assignment/conversion like this:
Variant floatSetting = 0.5f;
float fVar = floatSetting;

Variant boolSetting = true;
if (boolSetting) { return true; };

And to make this class work in general (map insert, returning from functions, passing as argument etc).

For starters, implicit conversions are not considered good in general; a converting function template is more readable. Next, the template constructor provided is hiding both copy and move constructors; it also covers the unusual casses of const rvalue and mutable lvalue inputs. You need constrain that template requires not std::same_as<Variant, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>. Then default the copy and move constructors.

@Red.Wave the copy and move constructors are already implicitly-defined as defaulted. But yeah, some constraining is necessary. Unfortunately std::remove_cvref_t is C++20, but std::decay_t can be used as a replacement here.

@JanSchultke decay does a bit too much; that's why we now have remove_cvref. I am a crazy dude that posts without testing first; I need be careful to write something that works, so sometimes a little overkill won't hurt.

There is no such thing as "implicit casting". Casting is explicit type conversion, by definition.

The greatest issue that prevents your code from working is that the forwarding constructor is unconstrained.
A forwarding constructor always needs to be constrained because it competes with the copy and move constructor.
In fact, in the scenario:
Variant a = /* ... */;
Variant b = a;

... the forwarding constructor wins in overload resolution against the copy and move constructor.
This scenario also happens down in GetValue
Therefore, you need to write something like:
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, Variant>, int> = 0>
Variant(T&& v) : value(v) {}

Having an unconstrained conversion operator template is also extremely fishy.
Your operator T would work for cases such as T = variant_t, or any arbitrary type that's not in the variant.
You should make sure that this template cannot be used for such cases, with:
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, variant_t>, int> = 0>
operator T() const

However, even if it worked, I wouldn't do any of this.
Implicit conversions are generally frowned upon.
They are especially bad here because std::get will throw an exception, so innocent looking code like

float fVar = floatSetting;


... can actually throw std::bad_variant_access.

How would it look with std::remove_cvref_t in place of std::decay_t ? I tagged it C++17 because of variant but I can use C++23 actually.

@ZaxFtw std::remove_cvref_t would be preferable, but either one does the same here. If you can use C++23, you should also use constraints instead of std::enable_if.

Implicit conversions are very dangerous, I wouldn't add them. Especially because GetValue can fail to find a setting. The default Variant that you return will throw if you try to convert it.
Do you need to expose Variant to the outside world at all? Presumably the users of these settings know what type they expect from a given key, you can require they specify it in GetValue.
class Settings
{
    using variant_t = std::variant<std::monostate, int, float, bool, std::string>;
public:

    template <typename T>
    struct Key
    {
        std::string_view key;
    };

    template <typename T>
    std::optional<T> GetValue(Key<T> key) const
    {
        std::shared_lock lock(mtx);
        auto iter = data.find(key.key);
        return iter == data.end() ? std::nullopt : std::optional(get<T>(iter->second));
    }

    template <typename T>
    void SetValue(Key<T> key, std::type_identity_t<T> value)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mtx);
        data.insert_or_assign(key.key, value);
    }

    Settings() {}
    ~Settings() {};

private:
    using SettingsMap = std::unordered_map<std::string_view, variant_t>;

    mutable std::shared_mutex mtx;
    SettingsMap data;
};

You can then use it like this
Settings settings;
Settings::Key<std::string> key{ "string" };
settings.SetValue(key, "hello");
std::optional<std::string> value = settings.GetValue(key); 


How would these functions with Key param be called here?
